# jQuery doesn't get clicked button's data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In this example, my button with id "delete" opens modal form for asking question like "Are you sure to want to delete this?"

```
<td><?=$row["id"]?></td>
<td><?=$row["site_host"]?></td>
<td><?=$row["site_name"]?></td>
<td><?=$row["site_user"]?></td>
<td><?=substr($row["site_value"], 0, 11)?>...</td>
<td><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus alert-danger" id="delete" data-id="<?=$row["id"]?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sitedelete"></i></td>
```

I'm passing modal form for now, If you want, i can share it with you also.
I have no problem with my PHP files, i just want to show you my jQuery codes:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var silid = 0;

    $("#delete").click(function(){ // this one is my button
        silid = $(this).data("id"));
    })

    $("#sitedelete").submit(function(event){ // i want to pass silid variable to this function. 
        event.preventDefault();
        alert(silid);
    });
});
```

But when i clicked #delete, it only gives me first row's id of fetched SQL data. Others are undefined or returns 0
I think i don't have problem for passing data to other functions, it only sees first row's id.

Thank You.

Comment: its because you are duplicating the id's. $("#") selector always select the first element with that specific id. You need to use class instead of it. Then your code will work fine

Comment: add something along `return confirm("Really delete ?");` at the end of your click event handler callback.

Comment: The table rows you are printing are in loops? If yes, this means that the `id` attribute is repeating itself as well. One page can have only one Id which should be unique.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi can you explain more?

Comment: use  `$(".alert-danger").click(function(){` instead of  `$("#delete").click(function(){`

Comment: Oh thanks i get it now. I was expecting that id values change per elements. Is there anyway to make it with id? Actually i don't want to use it with class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking `delete` as a class will allow you to use the same class again and again without any conflicts or issues.

`<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus alert-danger delete" data-id="<?=$row["id"]?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sitedelete"></i>`

and

`$(".delete").click(function(){`

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now! Is there any way to make with id or something else? I don't want to use it with class

Comment: As Id's are dynamically created therefore you cannot catch them like this. it will be a lot of code. Another way is to create a fucntion having id as a parameter. Then calling that function in every loop such as `myFunc('delete<?=$row["id"]?>')`. This will give a unique ID. and everytime the onclick event is fired, the function `myFunc()` will be fired and will perform what you are performing above

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple delete buttons they can not all have the same ID : `id="delete"`. Rather make each button use a `.delete` class name so that the selectors work as expected.

You will then need to change

```
$("#delete").click(function(){ // this one is my button
```

to

```
$(".delete").click(function(){ // this one is my button
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have same id's for all buttons. You can do something like this:

```
<i onclick="click('<?=$row["id"]?>')" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus alert-danger" id="delete" data-id="<?=$row["id"]?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sitedelete"></i>
```

And in javascript:

```
function click(id) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my example you dont need a CLASS nor an ID, so you are free to do what you want with it.

When pressing on the 'button' to open your modal, I'll get the data-id from the button.

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#sitedelete', deleteAction);

var silid = 0; 

function deleteAction(e) {
   var deleteButton = $(e.relatedTarget); // get triggering button
   var id = deleteButton.data('id');

   // now you have your "silid" value available + your delete modal is open.
}
```

Also, I'd like to note that using a `<i>`-tag as a button is not a good practise.